# Disable $httpProvider.interceptors.push for a specific url

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I have a problem with finding a solution about my $httpProvider in AngularJS.
I have a Accessservice which i handle response Error from server , this service can handle 401,404 .. http errors and make a redirection to a page .

But i have a specific url which i won't to apply this AccessService . How i can handle this ?

Config.js :

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyService');
```

MyServices:

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('MyService', function ($q, $location) {
return {
    responseError: function (rejection) {
        var code = rejection.status;

        if (code === 401) 
            $location.url('/auth');

        if (code === 403) 
            $location.url('/unauthorized');

        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
};
});
```

in My Controller :

```
$scope.sendForm = function(){

    CustomService.posting($scope.form).then(function(data){
        if(data.status == 200){
                // code when 200
                // no problem here
        }

        if(data.status == 415)
            // line of code
        if(data.status == 401)
            // line of code

    });
};
```

There's a way to disable this interceptors for a specific controller or a http request.?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: In AccessService, check the URL, and do nothing if it is that specific URL.

Comment: How ? this line $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AccessService'); is whriten in config.js

Comment: As I said: **In AccessService**. Not in the code adding it to the interceptors.

Comment: I edited the post , could you please re read the post. and tell me your approach. Thank You

Comment: `var url = rejection.config.url; if (url === specificUrl) return $q.reject(rejection);`

Comment: Thanks Man , But when i put this psuedo code? inside responseError function ?

Comment: It's not pseudo-code. It's code. Given that it uses a variable `rejection`, and that `rejection` variable is only available in the responseError function, yes, of course, that's where it should go. Don't just copy and paste code. Try to understand it. It's only two lines.

Comment: mm i understood what you wrote, so reject is responsible to catch the redirection.

Comment: What does your interceptor do? It examines the status of the response. If it's 401 or 403, it tells angular to navigate to another URL. If not, it does nothing (i.e. it just propagates the response to the next interceptor, or to the actual error callback(s)). What should the interceptor do? It should only check the status codes if the URL is not a specific URL. If it is a specific URL, it should do nothing (i.e. it should just propagate the response to the next interceptor, or to the actual error callback(s)). That's what my code does.

Comment: returning a rejected promise using $q.reject() is how a promise error callback allows transforming the original rejected promise into another rejected promise. Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/06/04/angularjs-promises-2/

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is surely possible, you just need to wrap your if's in more conditional logic.

```
if (rejection.config.url.match(/*regextomatchroute*/) {
    //handle the match
} else {
    // your current ifs
}
```